# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, on-duplicate-key

For loading huge amounts of data into MySQL, [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) is by far the fastest option. Unfortunately, while this can be used in a way INSERT IGNORE or REPLACE works, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not currently supported.

However, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` has advantages over `REPLACE`. The latter does a delete and an insert when a duplicate exists. This brings overhead for key management. Also, autoincrement ids will not stay the same on a replace.

How can `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` be emulated when using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: Variations on this are discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693737/mysql-fastest-technique-for-insert-replace-on-duplicate-of-mass-records

Answer (score 107, accepted):

These steps can be used to emulate this functionality:

1. Create a new temporary table.

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE target_table;
   ```
2. Optionally, drop all indices from the temporary table to speed things up.

   ```
   SHOW INDEX FROM temporary_table;
   DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;
   DROP INDEX `some_other_index` ON temporary_table;
   ```
3. Load the CSV into the temporary table

   ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file.csv'
   INTO TABLE temporary_table
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   (field1, field2);
   ```
4. Copy the data using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

   ```
   SHOW COLUMNS FROM target_table;
   INSERT INTO target_table
   SELECT * FROM temporary_table
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = VALUES(field1), field2 = VALUES(field2);
   ```
5. Remove the temporary table

   ```
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table;
   ```

Using `SHOW INDEX FROM` and `SHOW COLUMNS FROM` this process can be automated for any given table.

Comment: I suggest rather using `INSERT INTO target_table SELECT coloumn_name1, coloumn_name1 FROM temporary_table` because * will include the primary key and cause items with the same primary key (in the case of an auto_increment primary key) in the main table to be updated, otherwise this worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked for me after a little of SQL juggling. My SQL-fu is very rusty, nice to learn neat techniques like this.

Comment: Thanks from here too - works brilliantly - didn't think it was possible to do a ON DUPLICATE KEY with LOAD DATA INFILE, so never tried before.

Comment: Nice. I don't think so there's a need to `DROP` the indexes on the temporary table. You are dropping it once you are done with its use :)

Comment: If you have any problem with UNIQUE KEY in step 4, you can use `UPDATE target_table, temporary_table SET target_table.field1 = temporary_table.field1 WHERE target_table.field2 = temporary_table.field2`

Comment: @Jan is this advisable if the TEMPORARY TABLE contains a few million entries?

Comment: @verisimilitude - Dropping indexes will improve performance for loading data from file!

Comment: @Jan Quite interested in knowing the answer to Sammy Lee 's question

Comment: Steps 1) and 2) can be done in a single statement: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table SELECT * FROM target_table LIMIT 0;`

Comment: Note: If you use statement based replication, you should use a regular table instead of `TEMPORARY`. Otherwise you might [get into issues](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-temptables.html).

Comment: Only one load data query with insert and update. Is it possible?

Comment: Seeing that OP is dealing with duplicate keys, I would recommend removing the primary key constraint after creating the temporary table, as the new data may contain duplicates as well: `ALTER TABLE temporary_table DROP PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Be aware of what may happens to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column if the table has such.

Answer (score 5):

We can replace first (two steps) with below single query in [the answer shared by Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15271204/117259).

For steps 1 and 2 we can create new table with same reference structure and without any indexes.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table SELECT * FROM target_table WHERE 1=0;
```

Instead of.

1. Create a new temporary table.

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE target_table;
   ```
2. Optionally, drop all indices from the temporary table to speed things up.

   ```
   SHOW INDEX FROM temporary_table;
   DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;
   DROP INDEX `some_other_index` ON temporary_table;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Non-LOCAL Versus LOCAL Operation**

The LOCAL modifier affects these aspects of LOAD DATA, compared to non-LOCAL operation:

- It changes the expected location of the input file; see Input File
  Location.
- It changes the statement security requirements; see Security Requirements.
- **It has the same effect as the IGNORE modifier on the interpretation of input file contents and error handling; see
  Duplicate-Key and Error Handling, and Column Value Assignment.**

LOCAL works only if the server and your client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with the local_infile system variable disabled, LOCAL produces an error. See Section 6.1.6, “Security Considerations for LOAD DATA LOCAL”.