# Mysql load data infile specified column

Tags: mysql, sql-update, load-data-infile

I have a table with already filled data :

```
Table routeur_su 
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hostname           | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| code_site          | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ip                 | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ios                | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modele             | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| uptime             | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_polling       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

+--------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+
| hostname   | code_site | ip              | ios  | modele | uptime |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+
| <hostname> | 131123S0  | 126.x.x.x | NULL | NULL   | NULL   |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+
```

And I have a .csv file, that contains :

```
<hostname>;1/2/24 17:14:00;Cisco 1803
```

(the 2 others infos are the uptime and the model)

I want MySQL to **update** the row with the uptime and the model.
For that, i used this in a BASH script :

```
version_router_su_file="$DIR/working-dir/shver.csv"
db_routeur_table="routeur_su"
...
$mysql -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "load data local infile '$version_router_su_file' INTO TABLE $db_routeur_table fields terminated by ';'(hostname, uptime, modele) ;"
```

But nothing happens. I read the documentation about load data, and tried several things but... still not working.
I don't get any error with this code, it just don't update.

Creating a duplicate table like posted in
[MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271202/mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update)
Will consume a lot of resources when doing it for each table in my database. Isn't it any other way to do it ?

Comment: I think you have to add `replace` before `into`

Comment: But if i add replace, the foreign key constraint stops the process (on code_site)
Because replace delete the row, and add it again

Comment: But i think if you don`t do it, records with known keys are ignored.