# LOAD DATA INFILE if line not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have some big .csv files.

i want to load them to mySql with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

but the files have lines that the same.

how could i load the files to mySql without the same lines?

---

this is my source:

```
// Import csv data in table in respective rows.
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$position' INTO TABLE temp 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE $i LINES
        (CHROM, POS, ID, REF, ALT, QUAL, FILTER, INFO)";


// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($config,$sql)) {
    echo "Table populated successfully.\n";
} else {
    echo "Error populating table: " . mysqli_error($config) . ".\n";
}
```

---

in the mySql i have the columns: CHROM, POS, ID, REF, ALT, QUAL, FILTER, INFO.

i can know that it same lines if CHROM && POS equal in different lines.

i can have same lines JUST in different files.

Comment: Your English isn't very good, it's hard to understand what you want. You want to prevent an error if there are duplicate lines?

Comment: @Barmar no, maybe example will be better: if i have 3 files with the same line, i want that in mySql, that line will be just 1 time (not 3 times).

Comment: I don't think you can do that with MySQL. It can either ignore all duplicates or report all duplicates as errors, it doesn't care whether they're in the same file or not.

Comment: The primary purpose of the 'LOAD DATA INFILE ...' MySQL feature is speed and it will not bother with duplicates. You want to use the ' ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...' syntax one the data on, you can do it in two steps. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271202/mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0):

IGNORE INTO TABLE temp instead of INTO TABLE.
When you create the table use DISTINCT(field)