# LOAD DATA INFILE - Show number of rows imported gives wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've been trying to import a csv file into a mysql database using LOAD DATA INFILE.

Everything is working more or less correctly, but when I use mysqli_info() or mysqli_affected_rows() they each show that no rows have been imported for the query. Even though I see the rows are being correctly imported.

A simplified version of what I am trying to do (Fewer columns that I am actually importing):

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password123';
$database = 'database_name';

$connect = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

$files = scandir('imports/');

foreach($files as $file) {
   $import = 
        "LOAD DATA INFILE 'imports/$file'
        IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (@id, @name, @address, @product)
        set id=@id, name=@name, address=@address, product=@product";

    if(! $connect->query($import)) {
        echo 'Failed';
    }

    $connect->query($import);

    echo mysqli_affected_rows($connect);
}
```

mysqli_affected_rows() returns 0, while mysqli_info() states all rows have been skipped. Any idea why it's not displaying correctly?

Hopefully that's enough information. Thanks!

Edit:

I've been a bit too busy to work on this over the past few days, but I have decided that although it doesn't specifically answer my question Drew's answer of importing into a temporary table first seems to make the most sense so I have decided to go with that.

Comment: try: echo  $connect->affected_rows;

Comment: And ... *is* the data loaded?

Comment: $connect->affected_rows; shows nothing.

Comment: @MikeRobinson What do you mean? How do I know this? This is my first time trying to use load data infile, so assume I know nothing. Everything appears in the table as it should, if thats what you mean

Comment: What I meant was: if you empty the table, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, does it load? And, are the expected number of rows inserted?

Comment: Yes it does and the right number of rows are added

Comment: I would not be relying on `$connect->affected_rows` as ever a Rosetta stone for info. It is broken half the time.

Comment: What is the version of your MySQL server? mysql_affected_rows() C API function (do not mix this up with the function with the same name in php's MySQL extension) originally did not handle load data statements and returned 0 for them. Its behaviour was changed in v5.5.5

Comment: what about `echo  $connect->query($import)->num_rows;`

Answer (score 3):

Further clarification of my comment: `I would not be relying on $connect->affected_rows as ever a Rosetta stone for info. It is broken half the time.`

This is one recommendation. Perform your LOAD DATA INFILE into a worktable, not your final desired table. Once that is performed, you have successfully escaped the limitations of that functionality and can enjoy the fruits of [Insert on Duplicate Key Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (IODKU).

With the latter when I want to know counts, I get an assigned batch number from a control table. If you need help with that, let me know.

But I am stepping back to the point of having the data in the worktable now, with a batch number in hand. I then perform the IODKU from the worktable into the final table with the batch number coming along for the ride into a column in the final table (yes, I can tweak the schema to do that, perhaps you cannot). To get around any schema changes to existing table, and to find cases or allow for a row having multiple batch id's having hit it, a simple association table with id's can be used. An intersect table if you will.

If concurrency is an issue (multiple users likely able to do this concurrently), then a locking strategy (ideally INNODB row-level locking) is employed. If used, make it fast.

I then fetch my count off the final table (or intersect table) where batch id = my batch number in hand.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15271202) from Jan.

Comment: Although this does not strictly answer the question (why affected_rows() does not display the number accurately), this is definitely the approach I would recommend.

Comment: How about the part that says it is broken half the time. There are plenty of bug reports even from minor version upgrades. It is a mess. And the likes of PDO rowCount had to take other measures to keep some semblance of sanity.

Comment: I would be careful with that statement. Many bug reports are regarding mysql_affected_rows() API function are complaints about not supporting certain statements (such as load data), returning various results when encountering an error in its earlier versions (this was a documented behaviour). When raised in conjunction with a php api library, the issue may get even more complicated, since the version of the MySQL server may be different from the version of the C API against which the php api library was compiled.

Comment: I think the history and experience with [the C routine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) speaks for itself :p ... if things were so well documented and so less error prone we wouldn't spend a decent amount of time dealing with it all.