# Is there a load data infile equivalent for updating

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of data I need to update. currently I am using a sql file to do the update but that seems to be taking forever and ties up the database.The sql file I am using to update the data is below with a ton of update statements.

```
update table set column='whatever' where id = 5;
```

The command I used to load the data was.

```
mysql --local-infile data_db -e "LOAD DATA local INFILE '/home/me/loaddata.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id,start_date,stop_date,type_id)";
```

data is

```
1,2019-01-05,2019-01-06,7
```

Fixed my issue.  I reloaded the file with the replace option.

```
mysql --local-infile data_db -e "LOAD DATA local INFILE '/home/me/loaddata.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id,start_date,stop_date,type_id)";
```

Comment: Try this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15271204/2469308

Comment: Here is one more: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11816/160363