# Append new rows from a txt file into a MySQL table which already has data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got a MySQL table, call it TEST, which already has some 500K rows of data.
I wish to append new rows present in the text file, say ABCD.txt, to TEST. 
The file ABCD.txt also has some 700K rows of data.

I can think of a solution which is exporting data in a txt file from TEST, merging it with ABCD.txt and finally uploading it back in TEST.

Is there another way I can do that efficiently?

P.S. --> I am using command line to load data into TEST

Thanks
Neeraj

Comment: The answer is yes

Comment: Hi, can you let me know what the efficient way would be?

Comment: Read text file, check for duplicates, insert new rows

Comment: Use the `ignore`-keyword: [MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE ignore duplicate rows (autoincrement as primary key)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891337/mysql-load-data-infile-ignore-duplicate-rows-autoincrement-as-primary-key)