# MYSQL - Unable to resolve duplicate error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

Trying to complete step one of a project where I create a new table with

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (customerID SMALLINT,firstName VARCHAR(25),lastName VARCHAR(25),street VARCHAR(50),city VARCHAR(50),state VARCHAR(25),zipCode VARCHAR(10),telephone VARCHAR(15),PRIMARY KEY (customerID));
```

Then, I am supposed to upload a csv file from the application.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/codio/workspace/customers.csv" INTO TABLE Customers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

or

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/customers.csv' INTO TABLE Customers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

but both of these provide the error code

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '32767' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Opening the file and searching for 32767 only yields one result in the telephone line. There is no duplicate.  I have `DELETE FROM Customers` and `DROP TABLE Customers`.  Both times confirming the table is empty by

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Customers;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I have been arguing with this for hours and am unsure what else to do.  The worst part is I feel like I am not doing anything wrong.  But that is where you come in.  Fingers crossed.

I have deleted the table, cleared the table, recreated the table, at one point, went so far as creating a brand new file.

Comment: have you considered the [`IGNORE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425727) keyword?

Comment: Do you have more than 32767 rows in your CSV file you try to import? Do you have ids which are bigger than the value 32767?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your primary key as

```
customerID SMALLINT
```

which means that it can only hold values between -32768 and 32767. When you use the `LOAD DATA` statement any value outside this range gets truncated as mentioned in the manual for the [`LOAD DATA` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-column-assignments):

> - Invalid values produce warnings rather than errors, and are converted to the “closest” valid value for the column data type.
>   Examples:
>
>   - [...]
>   - An out-of-range numeric or temporal value is clipped to the
>     closest endpoint of the range for the column data type.

This means that your first new row with a larger `customerId` value than 32767 gets clipped to 32767. The second new row with a larger `customerId` value than 32767 gets clipped to 32767 as well, resulting in a primary key conflict.

The solution is to use a bigger integer type for the `customerId` column like `INT` or `BIGINT`.